# full Wide screen image

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to place this picture at the background of my page in a `div`. I'm trying to make it full screen "in width". so the size of the picture is `980x420`, but it just simply doesn't work. I know I'm missing something but I can't find it anywhere.

CSS

```
.Sil{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(../Images/TALENT.png) no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="Sil"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility your image is smaller than 980px. If that's the case you can change from `max-width: 100%;` to become `width: 100%'. Other option is to use`background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

[For More Information](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)! Go and Checkout...